# the parameter form in Oracle Reports 11g do not display when run from Oracle Forms 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracleforms, oraclereports

I have converted the oracle forms and reports 5 to 10g and then to 11g, the reports compiled and run successfully in 11g, but don't display the parameter form created in Reports Builder.

I am using web.show_document with '&paramform=yes' but the parameter form developed in Report builder do not display. only a default parameter form is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `paramform` parameter has been made obsolete since Oracle Reports 9i and it is simply ignored.

You need to create a form collecting required parameters and pass them in the URL as report parameters before running it, e.g `&document_id=2131&copy=yes`

Note that `NUMBER` and `DATE` parameters may have different formats and you need to be careful if the NLS parameters are different.

Also when passing `VARCHAR2` parameters make sure you escape using:

`utl_url.escape (pi_text, TRUE)`

so parameters containing special symbols, e.g. "Fab B&B" are passed correctly.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/migration/reports-guide-to-changed-functional-132446.pdf